# Autoplay video with flowplayer 5.0

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I would like to set the autoplay=true

I tried to do this:

```
 <div class="is-splash flowplayer" id="modern" data-key="$xxxx" data-fullscreen="true" data-native_fullscreen="true" data-autoPlay="true"> </div>
```

and this:

```
$("#player").flowplayer({
                swf:'flowplayer5.5.2/flowplayer.swf',
                embed:false,
                splash: true,
                wmode: 'opaque',
                autoplay: true,
                playlist: [
                            [{ mp4:    videoUrl
                            }]
                          ]
});
```

Both the solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

remove class `is-splash` and the config `splash:true`.
The autoplay won't work with splash.